# Permissions denied for Firebase Database swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I keep getting this error: missing or insufficient permissions, when I try to write to firestore database. I use it to save a user's name/last name; however, my rules are:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /countData/{anything=**} {
      allow read, write;

    }
  }
}
```

also, I used the same database for to save other things, which works perfectly fine. Only this one does not work. I don't know why.

Here is the code for writing to firestore:

```
                    db.collection("users").addDocument(data: [
                        "firstName": firstName,
                        "lastName": lastName
                    ]) { (err) in
                        if let err = err {
                            print("error saving name: \(err)")
                        }else {
                            print("Name successfully saved!")
                        }
                    }
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule is protecting the countData collection, but your code is trying to query the users collection.  The rules must always match the query.

```
    match /users/{anything=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
```